# Android - counting sensor updates

Tags: android, updates, sensors

I am trying to Make an app including proximity gestures, but for this I need to count sensor updates, could anyone tell me with a code example how to count sensor updates!

Comment: take a look at this tutorial http://android-er.blogspot.co.il/2011/09/monitor-proximity-sensor.html
.. and for the next time don't ask the same question twice..

Comment: Following along with @Elior's link, just set a global integer variable, declare it as 0 in the activity. Then, in the method onSenserEvent just increment the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Decalre a global variable in your activity as **count_events**.

```
private int count_events=0;
```

Then in your **onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)** function make the following changes:

```
     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor mySensor=event.sensor;
        int type=mySensor.getType();
        if(type==Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY ) {
             count_events++;
        }
```